# Save after Greasemonkey

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

I have a Greasemonkey script (in Firefox) that makes some changes to the state of a webpage by doing two things, removing a class from a DOM element and changing the definition of a style associated with a different class.  Works fine.

When I view source on such a page, it shows the changes my Greasemonkey script made to the page.

But when I save down a copy of the web page as "Web Complete", what is saved is the original state of the page, before my script ran.  Or maybe a fresh copy downloaded from the server, and saved without my script ever running on it.  This is not what I want.

Is there a way in Firefox to save locally the page in the state it's in *after* the script runs?